# Neural network cost is constant never changing during training

Tags: neural-network, classification, numpy, cost-function, implementation

I am trying to build a binary classifier to [predict a pulsar star](https://www.kaggle.com/pavanraj159/predicting-a-pulsar-star) with Single Hidden layer Neural Network.

But the cost on training dataset after almost 100 iterations has no change, following is the implementation with python numpy.

```
import os
import csv 
import numpy as np

def load_dataset(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as work_file:
        reader = list(csv.reader(work_file))
        total = len(reader)
        train_set = reader[:round(total * 0.8)]
        val_set = reader[:round(total * 0.2)]
        features = len(train_set[0][:8])
        x_train = np.zeros((len(train_set), features))
        y_train = np.zeros((len(train_set), 1))
        x_val = np.zeros((len(val_set), features))
        y_val = np.zeros((len(val_set), 1))

        for index, val in enumerate(train_set):
            x_train[index] = val[:features]
            y_train[index] = val[-1]

        for index, val in enumerate(val_set):
            x_val[index] = val[:features]
            y_val[index] = val[-1]

    return x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val

def activation(fun, var):
    val = 0.0
    if fun == 'tanh':
        val = np.tanh(var)
        # val = np.exp(2 * var) - 1 / np.exp(2 * var) + 1

    elif fun == 'sigmoid':
        val = 1/ (1 + np.exp(-var))

    elif fun == 'relu':
        val = max(0, var)

    elif fun == 'softmax':
        pass

    return val

def loss_calc(y, a):
    return -(np.dot(y, np.log(a)) + np.dot((1-y), np.log(a)))
    # return -(y * np.log(a) + (1-y) * np.log(a))

x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = load_dataset('workwith_data.csv')
norm = np.linalg.norm(x_train)
print(x_train)
x_train = x_train/norm
print(x_train)
# Weights inititaed in trasponsed shape
# 0.001 is the ideal weights multiplier else log loss goes nan due to log 0 or -ve
w1 = np.random.randn(x_train.shape[1], 3) * 0.0001
w2 = np.random.randn(3, 1) * 0.01
# baises over layers
b1 = 0.0
b2 = 0.0
cost = 0.0
dw1 = 0.0
db1 = 0.0
dw2 = 0.0
db2 = 0.0
samples = x_train.shape[0]
lr = 0.01
for i in range(1000):
    # forward pass
    z1 = np.matmul(x_train, w1) + b1
    a1 = activation(fun='tanh', var=z1)
    z2 = np.matmul(a1, w2) + b2
    a2 = activation(fun='sigmoid', var=z2)
    loss = loss_calc(y_train.T, a2)
    cost =  np.sum(loss)/samples
    print(cost)
    # Backprop
    dz2 = a2 - y_train
    dw2 += np.matmul(dz2.T, a1)/samples
    db2 += dz2/samples
    tanh_diff = 1 - np.square(z1)
    dz1 = (w2.T * dz2) * tanh_diff
    dw1 += np.matmul(dz1.T, x_train)/samples
    db1 += dz1/samples
    w1 = w1 - lr * dw1.T
    w2 = w2 - lr * dw2.T
    print('iteration ' + str(i) + ' cost'+str(cost))
```

Comment: At a first glance, you're not updating the biases, and I'm not sure whether you should be adding to the derivatives like that instead of just resetting them.  Try printing some of the weights in the loop, to see how they're progressing?

Comment: @BenReiniger I am updating biases..But for the sake of simplicity i tried with removing biases, resetting weights and printing weights to track them. Weights are changing (randomly increasing decreasing)  You can check my updated code here https://www.codepile.net/pile/3ANoRNr2